Tabulator js: properly show nested arrays as coulmns which could be searchable
I have a json data such as below that I want to generate a table using tabulator js like picture1 below. I followed the documentation to implement nested data, so I changed the data to correct format and pass the other object of the nested arrays to _children property, but the picture 2 has been generated. (dataTree: true,dataTreeStartExpanded: true, passed as options)
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    phone_numbers: [
      {title: "cell", phone_number: "123-456-789"},
      {title: "home", phone_number: "987-654-321"},
      {title: "office", phone_number: "987-654-321"},
    ],
    locations: [
      {title: "home", code: 123, address: "us"},
      {title: "office", code: 321, address: "canada"},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "alex",
    phone_numbers: [
      {title: "cell", phone_number: "123-456-789"},
      {title: "home", phone_number: "987-654-321"},
    ],
    locations: [
      {title: "home", code: 123, address: "us"},
      {title: "office", code: 321, address: "canada"},
    ]
  },
]

picture1
picture2
I will be pleased if you you have any idea to generate this which the nested arrays could be treat as a normal column ...

I think what you are looking for is column grouping, not nested data.  If you are able to change the data format, you can do something like this:


const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "john", phone_title: "cell", phone_number: "123-456-789", address_title: "home", code: 123, address: "us" },
  { id: "", name: "", phone_title: "home", phone_number: "987-654-321", address_title: "office", code: 321, address: "us" },
  { id: "", name: "", phone_title: "office", phone_number: "159-357-852", address_title: "", code: "", address: "" },
  { id: 2, name: "alex", phone_title: "cell", phone_number: "123-456-789", address_title: "home", code: 123, address: "canada" },
  { id: "", name: "", phone_title: "home", phone_number: "987-654-321", address_title: "office", code: 321, address: "canada" }
]

const table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  data: data,
  columns:[
    {title:"Id", field:"id"},
    {title:"Name", field:"name"},
    {
      title:"Phone Numbers",
      columns:[
        {title:"Title", field:"phone_title"},
        {title:"Phone Number", field:"phone_number"}
      ]
    },
    {
      title:"Address",
      columns:[
        {title:"Title", field:"address_title"},
        {title:"Code", field:"code"},
        {title:"Address", field:"address"}
      ]
    }
  ]
})
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.5/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.5/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>




Its better to say I'm looking for implementing data tree not just nested :) but anyway
reformat data from API is not an option, and mutating it for tabulator is not a good choice, because there thousands of records and its totally nested with multiple objects and arrays ... and if I do that, searching, selecting and etc will be mess :( even grouping rows wont handle the situation properly ...
